# How to send sms from android and display the reply below android code

Tags: java, android

I m about to build a new application which is like this..
[image: This is my idea]

user will type a phone number and will send to a specific number defined in main activity. the main function is checking directory, phone number details about owner and address. this message will be send to service network and when the network reply back i want display the reply below that.

can anyone do that kind of project..?
i got no idea to start..

Answer (score 1):

Look into Google Cloud Messaging Service: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

If your messages are less than 4Kb, then you could use this as some sort of IM or Chat application.

Comment: Why not? The service allows for both upstream and downstream message passing. You don't even have to spend money by using expensive cellular connection for SMS'ing

Comment: If you don't want to use phone numbers but just rely on data connection (wifi or cellular), then look at this app, it's open source: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.usikkert.kouchat.android and that might give u some ideas as well.

Comment: Is there any sample project..?

Comment: you mean sample project on how to use GCM feature?